# PHP CodeIgniter Session Driver to Store Securely in Session

Tags: php, codeigniter, azure, session

I'm trying to design a secure application for storing sensitive documents that need to be encrypted. I'm wanting to use Azure Key Vault to encrypt/decrypt data in my DB. With the Key Vault after submitting your credentials you get an access token that you need to store securely somehow in order to make calls to the API. The only solution i can think of is storing these as a session variable. With CodeIngiter you can specify the session driver as either files, database, redis or memcache. I was thinking if i used redis or memcache as the driver, would that mean the session variables are stored in memory instead of a file or database that could be accesses by an attacker? Would that make it more secure? I don't know much about memcache or redis yet. Or is there a better way to handle these access tokens.

Thanks

Comment: Can you store it as a file? Then just place it outside doc root and it'll be secure

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you mean store the actual documents outside of the server on a hard copy or something thats not possible, they need to be accessible by the user when they log in. If you mean store the access token outside of the doc root, how would i do that? Wouldnt anything i store on the server by defintion be inside the doc root? Sorry I'm kind of new to all of this

Answer (score 0):

First off let me just say I don't know much about azure or the tokens it uses. What I can say is if it is anything like the google api that gives you a `.p12` (file) key then you can simply place the file outside of the document root.

Example:

[image]

This is my site, all of my publicly viewable scripts and files (that aren't protected via .htaccess) are in the `/HTML/` folder (sometimes this is called `public_html`) and that acts as my document root e.g. `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` (`/opt/www/prezent/mysite.com/HTML/`).

As you can see I store my sessions and backups outside the HTML folder/doc root and thus none of this is viewable - only the server can access it. Hence it would be a good place to put sensitive information.

You could also probably put a folder inside your public html folder and protect it from all with a .htaccess file (I've never known them to fail).

Of course, this is all assuming you can save your token to a file.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Ok I understand what you're saying. Yes if it was to be stored in a file it would definitely be above public_html. But what if the server is compromised: Somehow someone gains access to the server and all of the files on it. Storing in a file in this case would not be secure. So the idea with key vault is information for decrypting your data is totally off-site. Unfortunately as users want to access their data, you need to store an access token somehow. I'm asking if i used memcache to put this in memory instead of a file, if that would be protected from an attack.

Comment: Memcached requires the say file or string or hash be retrieved from somewhere and stored in ram so you are back at a file or storing the token locally. And as you know ram is not a permanent means of storage, so even if you stored it and delete its presence on the server it will eventually be deleted from the ram. Memcached is not for permanent storage, just transient data. I'm really not seeing a way around storing the token somewhere that it would be vulnerable to a serious attack.

Comment: That being said, session aren't for long term storage either and if they are stored in your secured database you'll need the key before attempting to get the key (if that makes any sense).

Comment: Ah ok that's what i was thinking was probably the answer, with memcache there is still some sort of file linking the data to memory and that file could be accessed. Thanks for your help.